# 'plink' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. windows server 2012

Tags: jenkins

Thanks for looking into my question.

I have a batch script running on a windows 2012 machine, it internally calls pscp and plink executables. I have environment variables configured properly and my script is working fine.

If I call the same script through Jenkins, it says
**'plink' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Could you please help me with possible options to debug this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you set PATH in system properties restart jenkins instance and recheck ?

Comment: Thanks for prompt response Harsha. I did this several times.But, it's not reflected.

Comment: If i do echo %path%, it's printing environment variables properly.
if I do where plink, it says
"INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)."
if i run where plink through command prompt, it says.
C:\Windows\System32\plink.exe

Comment: I believe above commands are executed as part of jenkins job.... Can you try specifically mentioning plink.exe in your batch ..?

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved, if I run Jenkins slave with administrator account.